# How to get item id Jquery Sortable

Tags: jquery

i have this jquery function Sortable

```
$(".column").sortable({
                connectWith: ".column",
                handle: ".portlet-header",
                cancel: ".portlet-toggle",
                start: function (event, ui) {
                    ui.item.addClass('tilt');
                    tilt_direction(ui.item);
                },
                stop: function (event, ui) {
                    ui.item.removeClass("tilt");
                    $("html").unbind('mousemove', ui.item.data("move_handler"));
                    ui.item.removeData("move_handler");
                    var id = ui.item.attr("id");
                    alert(id);
                }
            });
```

and this my html code like a two card

```
 <div class="column">
                                    <div class="portlet">
                                        <div id="1" class="portlet-header">
                                            <div class="card mb-2 card-s">
                                                <div class="card-body">
                                                    Feeds
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

i am try to get  the div id but always tell me undefined please someone help !!

Comment: Try with `ui.item.find('.portlet-header').attr("id");`

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen doesn't work bro .

Answer (score 0):

```
   alert(this.id); // Where the item is dropped
      alert(ui.sender[0].id); // Where it came from
      alert(ui.item[0].id); // Which item
```